# Replace Group By clause with any other clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by

In below query, I am using `GROUP BY` clause to get list of recently updated records depends on updated date. But I would like to have the query without a `GROUP BY` clause because of some internal reasons. Can please any one help me to solve this.

```
SELECT Proj_UpdatedDate,
       Proj_UpdatedBy
FROM   ProjectProgress PP
WHERE  Proj_UpdatedDate IN (SELECT MAX(Proj_UpdatedDate)
                            FROM   ProjectProgress
                            GROUP BY
                                   Proj_ProjectID)
ORDER BY
       Proj_ProjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using TOP 1 should give you the same result assuming you meant the MAX(Proj_UpdatedDate):

```
SELECT Proj_UpdatedDate,
       Proj_UpdatedBy
FROM   ProjectProgress PP
WHERE  Proj_UpdatedDate IN (SELECT TOP 1 Proj_UpdatedDate
                            FROM   ProjectProgress
                            ORDER BY Proj_UpdatedDate DESC)
ORDER BY
       Proj_ProjectID
```

However your query actually returns multiple dates since it's GROUPED BY Proj_ProjectId (the max date for each project).  Is that your desired outcome - to show a list of dates that the projects were updated and by whom?

If so, try using ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT  Proj_UpdatedDate, Proj_UpdatedBy
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Proj_ProjectID ORDER BY Proj_UpdatedBy DESC) rn,
      Proj_UpdatedDate, 
      Proj_UpdatedBy
   FROM   ProjectProgress
  ) t 
WHERE rn = 1
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33034/8).  This assumes you are running SQL Server 2005 or greater.

Good luck.